# Job settings form resetting active/deactive attribute on saving changes in views.py

Tags: python, django

I wrote an active/deactive functionality for my job page. When a user changes some of the attributes of the job and saves the changes, the active/deactive functionality is set back to deactive. Below are my job_settings and active/deactive functions:

views.py:

```
@login_required
@user_is_type('communitypartner')
def job_settings(request,job_id):
    job = Job.objects.get(id=job_id)

    #if the request was a GET
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = JobEditForm(instance=job)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobEditForm(request.POST, instance=job)

        #check form validity
        if form.is_valid() :
            #get form info
            job = form.save(request)
            #job = form.save()
            #add new orgs/remove removed orgs here

            message = "Job {0} has been modified.".format(job.name)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)

        return render(request, 'main/job_settings.html', {'form':form,'job' : job})

@login_required
def job_status_update(request):
    status = request.GET['status']
    job_id = request.GET['Jobid'] 
    if status == 'Active':
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    try:
        #job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
        job.active = flag
        job.save()
        #write back
        return HttpResponse(status)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse(status)
```

I need help in fixing this issue and maintaining the original status of the active/deactive functionality

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I needed to add active/ deactive feature to the settings form. This way when all the attributes are re rendered this feature is not left out and set back to original.